¿Cómo doy formato a la letra de un código HTML?
Como asignar el color blanco y agrandar la letra del siguiente código. Muchas gracias
let meses = new Array ("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"); 
let diasSemana = new Array("Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"); 
let f = new Date(); 
document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear()); 


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Cual letra?? el resultado de esa función es una oración, que está compuesta de palabras y que a su vez se compone de letras, cual es la letra que quieres cambia de color y aumentar dfe tamaño?

Para dar formato al texto de una página HTML, se utilizan estilos, definidos en lo que se conoce como "hojas de estilo en cascada" (Cascade Style Sheets), de dónde proviene el acrónimo CSS.

Hojas de Estilo en Cascada (del inglés Cascading Style Sheets) o CSS es el lenguaje de estilos utilizado para describir la presentación de documentos HTML o XML (incluyendo varios lenguajes basados en XML como SVG, MathML o XHTML). CSS describe cómo debe ser renderizado el elemento estructurado en la pantalla, en papel, en el habla o en otros medios.

CSS, que actualmente va por la versión 3, es un tema amplio y una respuesta de StackOverflow no sería suficiente para cubrirlo. Hay muchos sitios con videos, tutoriales, how-to's, cursos y otros recursos que te pueden ayudar a aprender sobre el tema. También hay muchos libros y artículos.
Un sencillo ejemplo (dale clic al botón ejecutar para ver el resultado aquí mismo en la respuesta):


p {
  color: red;
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-color: yellow;
}

p > span {
  color: black;
  font-style: oblique;
}
<p>Hola <span>Noelia</span>!</p>



Recuerda que google es tu amigo:

Tutoriales sobre CSS
Libros sobre CSS
Cursos de CSS
Formato básico de texto en CSS

Además:

La entrada de la documentación de CSS
Wikipedia: CSS

Finalmente, tu script produce HTML, una vez tienes enlazada una hoja de estilos, es muy simple.
Puede ser que ya el elemento padre traiga el estilo, y no tengas que cambiar nada en tu sentencia, o si quieres usar un estilo particular, digamos con una clase, algo como:
document.write("<span class='fecha'" + diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear() + "</span>"); 

